# Changing Banshee's "Recently Added" option

Tags: banshee

I use the Banshee audio player and, for the most part, it does everything I need. However, I'd love to be able to tweak the "Recently Added" list. Basically, I buy more music than I can keep up with, and since Banshee limits recently to being "in the last month" albums are dropping off the list before I get to them.

Is there a way to alter the time limit for "recently"? If it's a source code tweak then I'm quite happy to make that and build my own deb file for installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Banshee's "Recently Added" playlist is just a pre-defined smart playlist, so you should be able to tweak its criteria to meet your needs.

1. Right click on the playlist name in the sidebar on the left, and select "Edit Smart Playlist".
2. In the window that opens, you can change the "Date Added" to some value greater than 1 month.

[image]

I actually prefer to have the "Recently Added" list contain a fixed number of songs instead of a time limit.  To do this, you can uncheck the box next to "Match" and instead check the box next to "Limit to." Then set Banshee to limit the playlist to *x* number of songs (mine is set to 500) selected by **Most Recently Added**.

Comment: Aha! So obvious once it's pointed out! :) Thanks!